# Aurelia Router Configuration in Multiple Model-Views

Tags: aurelia

Is it possible to configure the router from multiple view-models?

Something like the following?

```
class App {
  ...
  constructor(router) {
    this.router.configure(config => {
      config.map([{
        route: 'home',
        moduleId: 'home',
        nav: true
      }])
    })
  }
}
```

Alter the router configuration in other view-model:

```
class SomeOtherPage {
  ...
  constructor(router) {
    this.router.configure(config => {
      config.map([{
        route: 'someOtherPage',
        moduleId: 'someOtherPage',
        nav: true
      }])
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

from the [aurelia docs](http://aurelia.io/hub.html):

As with everything in Aurelia, we have strong support for conventions. So, you can actually choose to dynamically route rather than pre-configuring all your routes up front. Here's how you configure a router to do that:

```
router.configure(config => {
  config.mapUnknownRoutes(instruction => {
    //check instruction.fragment
    //set instruction.config.moduleId
  });
});
```

All you have to do is set the config.moduleId property and you are good to go. You can also return a promise from mapUnknownRoutes in order to asynchronously determine the destination.

Also, the router has an `addRoute` method that should work in your case to add the route later.

- [example usage of addRoute](https://github.com/cmichaelgraham/aurelia-typescript/blob/master/skel-nav-require-vs-ts/skel-nav-require-vs-ts/views/welcome.ts#L25-L29)
- [repo containing example usage](https://github.com/cmichaelgraham/aurelia-typescript)

Comment: I saw the config.mapUnknownRoutes() method in the docs, but couldn't find out how to use it for my purpose. The addRoute() method is what I was looking for. Both links helped me very much. Thank you.